# GLKit Rendering and iOS Device Orientation (Face Up / Down)

Tags: opengl-es-2.0, uiinterfaceorientation, glkit, uideviceorientation

I have an app with some projection matrix set-up code based on Xcode 4.5.2's OpenGL Game template. In the `update` function I set appropriate z-translation values for `baseModelViewMatrix` by querying `[[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom]` as well as `UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape:` and `UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait:`. This effectively lets me set the scale of the area rendered on screen on a per-orientation basis for each device. I also call `update` from `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` to maintain the correct rendering proportions for each orientation of the device during runtime.

This all works fine, however I've noticed that when the device is oriented either face-up or face-down my scene is not displayed, and I only see what appears to be an empty GLKView. Rotating the device to any orientation perpendicular to the ground plane restores the scene to its expected behavior. I tried checking `UIDeviceOrientationIsValidInterfaceOrientation:`, which seems like it should handle what I need, but did not see any difference in behavior.

My guess is that GLKit does some automatic updating of the GLKView when a change in orientation is detected, but I didn't find any clear answers on what might be causing this particular behavior. Any thoughts on what's going on? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a function like GLKMatrix4MakeLookAt, you need to make sure your look direction is not parallel with the up direction.  In the case of looking straight up or down, you'll need to adjust the camera's "up" vector to another value such as 0,0,-1 or 0,0,1.